# Gradle execution failed for task 'Project:processDebugManifest'

Tags: android, compilation, gradle, android-studio

I am starting using google play service API on Android and after read several tutorial and do it several ways I always have the same error.

```
Gradle: Execution failed for task ':Teste:processDebugManifest'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException (no error message)
```

To import the library of google play I copy the paste of goggle-play-service_lib to my project, including the jar file to my project structure.(I'm using Android Studio)

At the end it looks like this:

App AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.teste"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <permission
            android:name="com.metyou1.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.metyou1.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.teste.FullscreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="MYKEY"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

App build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile project(':google-play-services_lib')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

google-play-services_lib build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
```

Someone can help me??

Thanks ;)

Comment: On the post about the new build system, there are some samples on how to use the google play services with gradle (gpsdemos.zip). http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system

Comment: yes, I also tried that(my build.gradle is exactly the same!) but when I compile with android studio I got this error... :/

Comment: can you run it with '--stacktrace' and provide the output of that stacktrace? cheers,

Comment: It looks like you have the Google Play Services as a library module. The demo shows how to add Google Play services using a private repository (downloaded using the sdk manager).

Comment: This might be helpful: https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/4Yhpn6p9icf

Comment: i'm having exactly the same error - it compiled yesterday and then it suddenly stopped compiling by the same error...
I'm adding the play services by adding
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'
to my dependencies in gradle - and still the same error - when removing the library everything works
have you found a way to compile?

Answer (score 6):

Finally after hours of debugging i got a solution....

```
[AndroidManifest.xml:3, AndroidManifest.xml:3] Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='7'> but library uses minSdkVersion='8'
```

comes as Error-Message when using gradlew - so you need to set your minSdkVerison to 8 in your manifest and everything should be working

(Don't forget to edit the build.gradle of your project to minSdkVersion 8 - i just lost another half of an hour to that but now its working)

Comment: But what if I still want to use minSdkVersion 7? If I do a runtime check for the api level and only call the library if it's 8 or higher, I should be fine I guess. But it doesn't build.

Comment: it won't build cause the library needs to be compiled with the right sdkVersion - so you definitly need to set it to SDK Version 8

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this issue while add ActionBarShelock to project, by comparing to the older library I found that application tag is missing in manifest. By adding one line i fixed my issue.

```
<application />
```

Hope this resolves.